# On a jquery ajax call where the one of the keys has value "??", jquery converts the value to jQuery164042601801476224854_1371690944590

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do a,

```
var i = '{"xyz":"??"}'

 $.ajax({ url: '/someendpoint',type: 'post', dataType: 'json', success: null,error: null,data: i });
```

the post according to firebug is:

```
{"xyz":"jQuery164042601801476224854_1371690944590"}
```

If there is just one question mark, the post is

```
{"xyz":"?"}
```

as expected.

This probably has to do with escaping in the post body, but need details.

Looks like a jquery bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417

Comment: That looks like a bug in jQuery

Comment: Have you tried other versions of jQuery?

Comment: Just curious what happens if you make String i an object instead? i.e. var i = { "xyz" : "??" };

Comment: considering jQuery will do $.param on it, it will no longer be JSON.

Comment: @yalis: You shouldn't put the answer (that it was a bug) in the question. Instead, post an answer on your own question.

Answer (score 6):

What's happening is that jQuery is filling it in as if it were a callback parameter.  Just set `jsonp: false` in your options to keep this from happening.

Comment: @zerkms, I don't believe so... at least, I've had a version of jQuery (bug or not) that always filled in a `?` in the URL without JSON-P mode being explicitly enabled.  As others have said, this is probably a bug, but I bet turning jsonp off fixes it.

Comment: that was a bug in an older version of jQuery, it's fixed in recent.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a jquery bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417